# Convert String to Hexadecimal

Tags: java, numbers, hex, number-formatting, numberformatter

I want to convert this String "123456" to Hexadecimal `String.format("%016x", "123456")`

but I got an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at Asdfsaf.main(Asdfsaf.java:22)
```

Comment: Read up on the format patterns (especially about the conversion argument category for "x"). Also, what result would you expect: the hex representation of the byte array created from the string using a specific encoding or the hex representation of the parsed (hint hint) number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert a string to hexadecimal like that, only a number can be formatted with `%016x`.

You can fix this by parsing `"123456"`:

```
String.format("%016x", Integer.parseInt("123456"));
```

Answer (score 5):

The value fo `x` must be an integer.

```
String.format("%016x", Integer.valueOf("123456"));
```

Result:

```
000000000001e240
```

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace stating

```
x != java.lang.String
```

States it clearly that String can not be converted to hexadecimal.
You should parse it into an integer first before you convert it into hexadecimal.

For parsing you can use

```
Integer.parseInt(stringVariable);
```

So your line of code would become:

```
String.format("%016x", Integer.parseInt("123456"))
```

Hope i helped.